# Woocommerce Variation swatches plugin cross out not matching attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

[image: Variation Swatches Plugin For Woocommerce]

Here is a screenshot of how the variations displayed when I selected first attribute (Size), it doesn't show the matching colors or doesn't cross out unmatching colors like the screenshot below (This is a premium plugin called Improved Variable Product Attributes Plugin). 

[image: Improved Variable Product Attributes Plugin]

Is there any way to cross out unmatching attributes in **Variation Swatches Plugin For Woocommerce** by adding simple Javascript?

After some trial and error tries, I wrote a little bit of code.
Anyone else has better contributions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I wrote this below code and added to 
 the click event in `wp-content\plugins\variation-swatches-for-woocommerce\assets\js\frondend.js` file.

**Add the below code at the end of onclick event**

```
/*
* Not Available display Hack
*/
                    var which = $el.closest( '.value' ).parent('tr').siblings();  which.removeClass('curr-select');
                    which.toggleClass('curr-select');
                    var available_value_select = $('.curr-select .value').find( 'select' ),
                    other_swatches = which.find('.swatch');
                    other_swatches.removeClass('tawvs-no-stock');

                if($el.hasClass('selected')) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                    other_swatches.each(function(index, el) {

                        console.log($( this ).data('value') +' - '+  available_value_select.find('option[value="' + $( this ).data('value') + '"]').val() +' - '+ available_value_select.find('option[value="' + $( this ).data('value') + '"]').length);

                            if( !available_value_select.find('option[value="' + $( this ).data('value') + '"]').length && !$(this).hasClass('selected'))
                                $( this ).addClass('tawvs-no-stock');
                        });

                    },200);
                    // console.log(available_value_select);
                }

/*
* Not Available display Hack
*/
```

**Eg :**

```
$form
    .addClass( 'swatches-support' )
    .on( 'click', '.swatch', function ( e ) {

// code here
})
```

Also add this css code of cross out in `wp-content\plugins\variation-swatches-for-woocommerce\assets\css\frondend.css`

```
.tawvs-no-stock:before, .tawvs-no-stock:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    content: "";
    width: 0px;
    height: 26px;
    display: block;
    border: solid #F44336;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    left: 18px;
}
.tawvs-no-stock:after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

**Results after adding this code snippet**

[image: Demo 1]

[image: Demo 2]

[image: Demo 3]