# Adding an "out-of-stock" class to variations shown as swatches - WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to figure out of way of adding an "out-of-stock" class to WooCommerce variations shown as swatches when their stock level is at 0.

I've found multiple ways of "greying out" out of stock variations when they are displayed in the standard WooCommerce drop down list - code shown below:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_active', 'grey_out_variations_when_out_of_stock', 10, 2 );
function grey_out_variations_when_out_of_stock( $grey_out, $variation ) {

if ( ! $variation->is_in_stock() )
    return false;
    return true;
}
```

However, this does not work when using a plugin to show my variations as swatches.

I currently have a size attribute, and have used a plugin to shown each size as a separate box that can be selected. Similar to what is shown in this thread: [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45117773/woocommerce-variation-swatches-plugin-cross-out-not-matching-attributes)

Is there some PHP, or JS that i could use to add a new stock to out of stock variations, which will then allow me to alter the CSS. Showing them as a red box, with a cross through it for example.

During my search so far, i have come up empty handed, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a particular WooCommerce add on plugin to show the swatches?

Comment: I've been using a couple, just to see if anything changed between them both.
Plugin 1: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-variation-swatches/
Plugin 2: https://wordpress.org/plugins/variation-swatches-for-woocommerce/

Comment: I haven't used either of those plugins, I've written a solution using the plugin "WooCommerce Variation Swatches and Photos" which is sold on the WooCommerce site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I wrote this code for plugin [WooCommerce Variation Swatches and Photos](https://woocommerce.com/products/variation-swatches-and-photos/).  What is will do is add a class called **out-of-stock** to any variation with zero stock.  You will need to ensure that the variations are setup with **Manage Stock** checked.  When a variation has zero stock then the class is added to the variation link.  You can then style the class however you want to show it is disabled.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_swatches_get_swatch_anchor_css_class', 'add_swatch_out_stock_class', 10, 2);

function add_swatch_out_stock_class( $anchor_classes, $swatch_term ) {
    if ( is_product() ) {
        global $post;
        $product = wc_get_product($post);

        if ( $product->get_type() === 'variable' ) {
            foreach( $product->get_available_variations() as $variation ) {
                $product_variation = new WC_Product_Variation($variation['variation_id']);

                if( $product_variation->get_stock_quantity() === 0 ) {
                    foreach( $product_variation->get_variation_attributes() as $var_attribute) {
                        if( $swatch_term->term_slug === $var_attribute) {
                            $anchor_classes .= ' out-of-stock';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $anchor_classes;
}
```

To show the size labels inside the swatch you can remove the text-index property using this filter.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_swatches_picker_html', 'remove_text_indent', 10, 2);

function remove_text_indent( $picker, $swatch_term) {

    return str_replace('text-indent:-9999px;', '', $picker);
}
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you for this. I have used this code with the plugin files on github, and it does work, however, on that specific plugin i cannot get the variations to display in a box. 

For example, my sizes variations should be displayed like so:
[S] [M] [L] [XL] but i'm unable to do this. If i figure it out, i will be using this.

I've tired to do something simialr for the other plugins, but no luck in doing so!

Comment: @JoshSouthern It's not a free plugin so it wouldn't be available on GitHub.  What's the URL of where you got it from?

Comment: Is there a way I can message you privately with that URL? I wouldn't want to be putting the link everywhere if i shouldn't be able to get hold of the code.

Comment: @JoshSouthern or I think you can start a chat with me as described in this link https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231544/how-to-start-chat-with-a-particular-user

Comment: Unfortunately I can't seem to get the chat to work, I think this is probably to do with my low reputation number. But yes, that text is within the woocommerce-swatches.php file.

Comment: @JoshSouthern I've updated my answer to show you how to show the size label inside of the swatch.

Comment: Thank you for the help so far Andrew. Your update works like a charm. I'm now trying to figure out how to disable the swatch (so user can click it, but it is still visible) now I can add the out-of-stock CSS. Unfortunately it is the DIV that is clickable, and now the <a> inside it. Perhaps some jQuery would work.

Comment: @JoshSouthern yes that's probably your only option as there are no filters to disable it.

Comment: Been messing around with the jQuery functions, and think I've come up with a way.
`jQuery('.swatch-anchor.out-of-stock').parent().addClass('out-of-stock'); 
  jQuery('.select-option.swatch-wrapper.out-of-stock').click(function() {
    return false`
So far it has worked, and the user cannot click on the swatch that is out of stock. My only issue would come from having more than one attribute - colour, size, but for now, I only have the one. As i mentioned in a previous comment, thank you for the help Andrew, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: @JoshSouthern thanks mate, if you could upvote my answer and accept it that would be great :)

Comment: @AndrewSchultz this works good, however it injects the `.out-of-stock` 6 times in the swatch-anchor element. Is this related with line `foreach(...`? How can this be resolved?

Comment: @Demian most certainly.  Been ages since I looked at this so I don't remember how it all works.  As a quick fix you can do a check of the anchor classes to see if the class has already been added before adding it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to hide Color Swatches (Color option only) then you can use this put before  tags.
NB! You have to check that classes are same for plugin swatches what you use example change .tawcvs-swatches for your style class what plugin uses.

```js
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
    (function ($) {
        function readyFn() {
            $( ".variations_form" ).on( "woocommerce_update_variation_values", function () {
            let $swatches = $('.tawcvs-swatches');
            $swatches.find('.swatch').removeClass('hidden');
            $swatches.each(function(){
                let $select = $(this).prev().find('select');
                $(this).find('.swatch').each(function(){
                    if (!($select.find('option[value="'+ $(this).attr('data-value') +'"]').length > 0)) {
                        $(this).addClass('hidden');
                    }
                })
            })
        } );
        }

        $(document).ready(readyFn); 
    })(jQuery);

</script>
```